# Border Layout Spacing/Margins

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, margins, grid-layout

for my beginner Java class we made an automated Tic-Tac-Toe game, and now we are creating a GUI to play it on. However, I'm having a lot of trouble getting the spacing/margins right. So far, I've just been trying to get the general framework for the GUI, and then I'm going to go back and actually implement the Tic-Tac-Toe game I have already made. So, far, I have this:

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.border.*;

public class ITTTGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    //butimport javax.swing.border.*;tons
    private JPanel sizePanel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JPanel displayPanel;
    private JPanel bottomPanel;
    private JTextField size;
    private JButton rebuildButton;
    private JButton[] buttons;
    private JLabel output;

    //constructor
    public NumberChooser(){
        setTitle("BitchFace");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //content pane
        Container cp = getContentPane();

        //add a panel for the size
        sizePanel = new JPanel();
        sizePanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5) );//adds margin to panel
        sizePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        size = new JTextField("3",5);
        sizePanel.add(new JLabel("N"));
        sizePanel.add(size);
        rebuildButton = new JButton("Rebuild");
        rebuildButton.addActionListener(this);
        sizePanel.add(rebuildButton);
        //add bottom panel for output

            sizePanel.add(new JButton("Player:"), BorderLayout.EAST);
            sizePanel.add(new JButton("Move:"), BorderLayout.EAST);
            sizePanel.add(new JButton("Winner:"), BorderLayout.EAST);


        //add a panel for the numbers
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5) );//adds margin to panel
        buildButtonsPanel();

        //add bottom panel for output
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5) );//adds margin to panel
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton("New Game"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton("Advise"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton("Quit"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);




        //add panels to main pane
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add(sizePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        cp.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cp.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
    }

    //this is a helper method to rebuild the buttons panel
    private void buildButtonsPanel(){
        int n = 3;
        try{
            n = Integer.parseInt(size.getText());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        buttonPanel.removeAll();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(n,n,4,4));
        buttons = new JButton[n*n];
        for(int i=0; i < buttons.length; i++){

            buttons[i] = new JButton("*");
            buttonPanel.add(buttons[i]);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        pack();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object s = e.getSource();
        //check to see if the action came from the rebuild button
        if(s == rebuildButton){
            buildButtonsPanel();
        }
        //otherwise it came from the grid

    }

    //entry point
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //create the GUI
        NumberChooser nc = new NumberChooser();
        nc.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

It doesn't have to be exact, just generally the same. 
And also there is no X or winner variable since I haven't implemented that. I also tried changing the margins from (5,5,5,5) to like (1,1,1,1), but that didn't change anything at all so that also confused me.

Any help with this, or how to generally go about this assignment would be appreciated.

(And it's not accepting my images. Sorry.)
Links are:

The problem is that is looks like this: 
[image: What my GUI looks like]

https://i1224.photobucket.com/albums/ee362/Devolutor/COPimage1_zps459f304b.png

And it is supposed to look like this: 
[image: What it is supposed to look like]

http://i1224.photobucket.com/albums/ee362/Devolutor/COPimage2_zps8981c846.png

Comment: A search of the page shows the first '?' occurs in *"Not the answer you're looking for?"*.  What is *your* question?

Comment: Make sure not to change your setTitle() line when you turn it in... yes I realize this question is 2 years old.

Answer (score 2):

To have more space between the buttons, use a number of pixels beiiger than 4 for the grid layout:

```
buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(n,n,4,4));
```

To have a grid rather than a flow at the right side, use a GridLayout (just like you did for your buttons, but with 4 rows and 2 columns) rather than a FlowLayout.